# Custom seperate Single.php

Tags: single

In my site I have a blog where each posts loads single.php like normal wordpress installation.
I also have a "shop" custom page where each links also loads single.php but the permalink is different. For normal blog post the permalink goes like this:

```
http://www.mysite.net/2012/07/02/blah-blah-blah/
```

For custom shop page the permalink goes like this:

```
http://www.mysite.net/shoppage/blah-blah-blah/
```

What I am trying to do is not load default single.php when clicking on individual post from shoppage template. I want to load a custom single.php with my own changes added. Is it possible?

Relevant part for index.php:

```
    <h2 class="post_title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                        </h2>
                        <!-- /.post_title -->

<div class="post_meta">
                            <?php echo __('Posted on ', 'wizy') . get_the_date(); ?> <?php _e('in ', 'wizy'); echo the_category(', ');?> by <?php the_author(); ?>
                        </div>


                        <!-- /.post_meta -->
```

relevant part from shoptemplate.php:

```
<div class="project_container">

<center><h2 class="post_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></center>

                            <a href="<?php echo $thumb_src[0]; ?>" class="project_thumb zoom">
                            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('project_thumb_midd'); ?>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo TIMTHUMB; ?>?src=<?php wizy_assets_uri(); ?>/images/image_placeholder.png&amp;w=300&amp;h=250&amp;zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>
                            <!-- /.post_thumb -->

                            <div class="project_desc">
                                <?php the_content('',FALSE,''); ?>

                            </div>
                            <!-- /.post_excerpt -->

                            <?php if( $pos = strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--more-->') ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="more_link"><?php _e( 'View Project &rarr;', 'wizy' ); ?></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </div>
```

I know my way around with wordpress, but not so much with php

Comment: are the shop posts a custom post type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help, if you need more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Simply put, Wordpress looks for template files in the following order for single posts:

- `single-{post_type}.php`,
- `single.php`,
- `index.php`.

If you want to override the standard `single.php` file, that's how (for a custom post type only, as you're using)

Comment: Your answer is much better than mine. I will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Just create another single.php as single-shoppage.php and it should load the new php. have to do nothing else. Just edit single-shoppage.php to see changes to that post type.